# How to locate and use <div> inside <div> using jQuery without giving reference through ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-clone

This is a sample structure of the code

```
<div id="original">
  <div id="box1">
    <span></span>
    <div id="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <span></span>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <span></span>
    <div id="3"></div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div id="boxn">
    <span></span>
    <div id="n"></div>
  </div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Help me to locate `div id="boxn"` using jQuery without giving reference through ID, classes, or maintaining any variable

Any solution other than jQuery will also be helpful

Edit 1 : Well, actually I am trying to clone such div and appending inside `div id="original"` without referring to ID's because there would be multiple divisions and difficult for me to work upon then. To be clear I am wondering to make a function which I can use on different pages without referring to ID's

Edit 2 : I have changed my code for better understanding of problem

Comment: _"without giving reference through ID"_... Why? It's the fastest way to query the DOM

Comment: why without reference to ID? that's ID's job, to be located.

Comment: Well, actually I am trying to clone such div and appending inside `original` without referring to ID's because there would be multiple divisions and difficult for me to work upon then. To be clear I am wondering to make to function which i can use on different pages without referring to ID's

Comment: Then use classes instead of IDs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div > div:nth-child(3)')
```

But I really don’t know why you would use such a selector.

Comment: The problem that it will select 3rd div child for ALL the divs in the DOM. The question is too broad which makes it impossible to provide a solid answer

Comment: Well, actually I am trying to clone such div and appending inside original without referring to ID's because there would be multiple divisions and difficult for me to work upon then. To be clear I am wondering to make to function which i can use on different pages without referring to ID's

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` with `$("#original > div:nth-child(3)")`

Updated:

If you want to get nth child, you can create a variable to store the index as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = 3;
console.log($(`#original > div:nth-child(${n})`).html())
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = 3;
console.log($(`#original > div:nth-child(${n})`).html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="original">
  <div id="box1">
    <span></span>
    <div id="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <span></span>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <span></span>
    <div id="3"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="box4">
    <span></span>
    <div id="4"></div>
  </div>
  
  
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution really works but I would be having  _n_ times clone for them

Comment: why need clone it? should clear requirement in question

Comment: Sorry, I am new here I will try to make question more clear